# MPMoviePlayerController in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an app for iOS in Xamarin and I have an UICollectionView with MPMoviePlayerController in their cells.

My problem is that I cannot use the MPMoviePlayerController controls in order to Play / Pause the video because the UICollectionView has the touch events.

I have tried setting to false in the UICollectionView the CanCancelContentTouches field and setting to true the UserInteraction but it doesn't work.

How can send the touch event to the MPMoviePlayerController?

Thanks in advance!